# Best Practice for storing HistoryOfAllEvents and EventDetails

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-schema

I'm new to database design and I'm trying to fix an existing mess.

I have a list of events (with columns of parameters for the events), and each event has another table of details for the event.
For example, this could be a bunch of usages of scientific instruments, and then each run-event has a bunch of data collected while it was running.

What would  you recommend as a structure for this?

My first idea is to have one table for the usage history, and then each row links to its own table that stores its collected data.  But how do I link the row to its table?  Is there something like a foreign-key to a whole table?

My second thought is to have one, single, table of collected data, and use P-key, F-key to link the usage history to the collected data.  But if I have hundreds of instruments, each collecting thousands of datapoints every day, then this one table will get very big (maybe a GB/year).  Would that be OK? (I'm a microcontroller/embedded engineer, so anything over a MB seems huge to me.)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This really depends on the particular implementation. Would you be able to show us some sample data? I think either of your ideas could work, but which is best -- or whether there's a third, better way -- really depends on what your data looks like.

Comment: By the way, adding 1GB of data per year should not be a problem at all. I think a lot of people would consider a database of several gigabytes to be pretty small.

Comment: @JeffRosenberg  Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post any real examples, so I must use hypotheticals.  Can you advise on what factors would make one method better than another?

Comment: In my hypothetical situation, the "usage history" table has a bunch of small nvarchar(), Int, Float and Datetime, and one big nvarchar.   The "event details" are a bunch of ints and floats.

Comment: For me, it's just a question of which will result in the least wasted space. If using your first method, how many child tables would you need? If using your second, how many of the columns in the usage table would be reusable, and how many would be used for only certain instruments?

Comment: @JeffRosenberg  Your second question brings up an excellent point I hadn't considered.  Currently, virtually all columns are used by all instruments, but in the future I'd like to be able to expand this program to handle data for other "scientific instruments".

For my idea #1, how do I link a row to a table?

Comment: @JeffRosenberg And to answer the first part of you question; depending on my customer, they may generate 4 child tables per week, but other clients may generate 600 every day.

Comment: I'd recommend your second method -- just having one large table. However, to answer your question, the way to link a row to a table is basically to have multiple nullable foreign keys linked to different tables, and only fill in the appropriate one. That can get unwieldy if you have a lot of tables to link to, so you'd want to design the tables to get as much reuse as possible in that case -- with only a few child tables, each used for a certain category of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments above, I'd say your second option seems best-- having a single table of collected data, linked by a foreign key. As long as you index your foreign key, you should have no problem with tables that are several GB in size.

Without a look at your data, I can't really suggest if there are any alternatives that might be better, but that should do just fine.